# Are PHPUnit mocking functions still really useful since we can use anonymous classes in PHP7?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, php-7

I'm quite new in PHPUnit, and rewriting my old-fashioned unit tests to use it.
I recognize the added value of the framework to make the tests more readable, simple, generate reports, automate... But I am still divided as to the mocking / stubbing features. Are they still really useful since we can use anonymous classes in PHP7 ?

For example, is :

```
$stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);
$stub->method('doSomething')
    ->willReturn('foo');
```

really supposed to be more elegant/readable/simple than :

```
$stub = new class extends SomeClass {
    protected function doSomething() { return 'foo'; }
};
```

In my opinion, the second proposition is much more readable and accessible for developers who dont know the framework.

Is there still a good reason to use this features ?

To put it a different way, is there something I can do with PHPUnit's mocking/stubbing functions that I can't do using anonymous classes ? Or is it a matter of preferences / use cases ?

Comment: The question is very subjective, largely asking for opinions, so likely to be closed soon

Comment: However, it's possibly still easier/more readable to write mocks that can be used to return different values based on the number of times that methods are called, or based on specific input values - especially with the aid of libraries like mockery - than with Anonymous Classes

Comment: @MarkBaker maybe this is the good answer. Basically, my question can be rephrased as follow : is there something I can do with PHPUnit's mocking/stubbing functions that I can't do using anonymous classes ? Or is it, as you said, a matter of preferences ?

Comment: Though somewhat coincidentally, just yesterday I actually submitted a proposal to couple of PHP Conference CfPs about using Anonymous Classes in PHP7, which includes using the as an alternative to mocks in unit testing

Comment: There are some differences. The biggest one that I can think of is that the methods `expects()` and `with()` act as assertions. `$myMock->expects($this->once())->method('blah')->with($param1, $param2)` is actually 2 separate assertions. Asserting the method will run exactly once, and that it is passed the expected parameters.